# How can I get the data in Vue from Node.js

Tags: javascript, express, vue.js

**index.js**

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    var cart = req.cookies.cart;
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'../../src/components/cart.html'),cart);
})
```

**cart.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="app" class="container mt-3">
        <h2> cart View </h2>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {

        }
    })
</script>
```

I want to get cookies in vue..

How to get 'cart' data in Vue ?

Is that right way make `res.send('../cart.html',cart)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do request from vue to your server to fetch the data. You can use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for that.

**BUT** in this case you are sending cookies to server and trying to return cookies from request, why? You can take your cookies on front-end without any request, use [js-cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-cookie).

```
Cookie.get('cart')
```